# how can i fix the syntax error in the file name or its path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

when I run that code it comes out to me this error:

> **IndexError: string index out of range**

I have no idea why I comes out to me this error and I don't have
any note but if you want to ask me about any thing don't hesitate

```
letters_string = "d  g o"
letters_list = []

# Check Space
def convert_letters_to_list(word):
    """
    This Function takes the letters from the users
    and checks if users put more than one space 
    between letters if True It Removes The extra Spaces
    """

    if word[0].isspace() == True:  
        convert_letters_to_list(word[1])
  
    elif word[0].isalpha() == True:    
        letters_list.append((word[0])) + convert_letters_to_list(word[1:])     

    else:    
        convert_letters_to_list(word[1:])


convert_letters_to_list(letters_string)
print(letters_list)
```

Comment: At some point `word` will only contain 1 character, so `word[1]` will give you the index out of range error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You function is recursive so after a while, any letter index past 0 will be out of the original string.

Here is a fixed version of your code.

```
letters_string = "d  g o"
letters_list = []

# Check Space
def convert_letters_to_list(word):
    """
    This Function takes the letters from the users
    and checks if users put more than one space 
    between letters if True It Removes The extra Spaces
    """

    if word[0].isalpha() == True or (word[0].isspace() and  not  letters_list[-1].isspace()):    
        letters_list.append((word[0]))
    
    if len(word) == 1:
        return

    convert_letters_to_list(word[1:])


convert_letters_to_list(letters_string)
print(letters_list)
```